# Any way to disable the app crash dialog?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, crashes, crash-reports

At least two times that I can remember, my phone has got stuck in a crash loop. That is, an app crashes, the OS starts it again in the background, then it crashes again. This repeats ad nauseam. This generally makes any attempt to fix the problem either impossible or spectacularly frustrating. Is there any way to disable the dialog, make it a notification, or limit the occurrences?

If it helps, I'm using CM 12 and have rooted.

Comment: You could uninstall the app if it is crashing. However if it is a system app you can reflash CM12 from recovery mode and wipe cache without need to wipe your data.

Comment: I always try to stop and wipe the app cache then. Additionally I recommend to deactivate internet while this is happening, this avoids some of the apps starting. But you are right, this is very annoying and should be improved in CM. I created a [feature request](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-6544) for it.